# Keyword checking in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, functions, plugin-gravity-forms

In Gravity Forms I'd like to include a small keyword checker that is checking the user's message for "spammy" words and stops sending the entry to the admin. For this a hidden field changes it's value. I have this code included in my functions.php so far

```
function strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {
if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
foreach($needle as $what) {
    if(($pos = stripos($haystack, $what))!==false) return $pos;
}
return false;
}

/*
* Our bad words validation function
*/


add_action('gform_pre_submission_1', 'keywords_check'); 

function keywords_check($validation_result){
$form = $validation_result["form"];


$stop_words = array(
    'outsource', 
    'Madam', // this covers all variations of 'Sir/Madam' 'Sir /Madam' 'Sir/ Madam' 'Sir / Madam' etc
    'SEO',
    'long term relationship',
);

$stop_id = array();

foreach($_POST as $id => $post)
{
    if(strpos_arr($post, $stop_words))
    {
        /*
         * We have a match so store the post ID so we can count it
         */ 
         $stop_id[] = $id;
    }
}

if(sizeof($stop_id) > 0)
{
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;


    $_POST['input_55'] = "No";

}

}
```

There seems to be a problem with the part in the very beginning of this code, especially with

```
foreach($needle as $what) {
    if(($pos = stripos($haystack, $what))!==false) return $pos;
}
```

After sending the form I get the following warning

```
Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 109
```

I have several php noob trial and error hours behind me before asking this question. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in function `strpos_arr`. If your bad word is in `$pos = 0` than the output will always be `false`. Replace the line:

```
if(($pos = stripos($haystack, $what))!==false) return $pos;
```

with:

```
if(($pos = stripos($haystack, $what))!==false) return true;
```

Your `keywords_check` function can be much simplified by using it as Gravity Forms field validation filter:

```
function keywords_check( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $stop_words = array(
        'outsource', 
        'Madam', // this covers all variations of 'Sir/Madam' 'Sir /Madam' 'Sir/ Madam' 'Sir / Madam' etc
        'SEO',
        'long term relationship',
    );

    if ( strpos_arr( $value, $stop_words ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Illegal words entered';
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_2_4', 'keywords_check', 10, 4 );
```

Notice two numbers in 'hook' name in this example. 2 - form id, 4 - field id. Adjust those numbers to match your form.

Answer (score 0):

I have a plugin that will also handle this via the default WordPress comment blacklist functionality: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-comment-blacklist/

Comment: The GP Blacklist plug-in isn't working for us on forms. We're getting identical spams after blocking words within that spam message. Any ideas why?

Comment: No ideas offhand but we'd love to dig in via support: https://gravitywiz.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an addition to Frank P. Walentynowicz's answer. Make it so you will not need to constantly edit your `functions.php` when you want to add/remove to the `$stop_words` array.

You can achieve this by utilizing the built-in [Wordpress Comment Blacklist](https://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam#Comment_Blacklist) feature.

Everything you save in the wp blacklist is stored in the database in the WP_Options table under `blacklist_keys`. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference

At the start of your `keywords_check` function you can get these keys and store them in a variable:

```
$blacklisted = get_option('blacklist_keys');
```

Now, turn those into a proper array:

```
$stop_words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $blacklisted);
```

All the stop words will be pulled from the WP blacklist. You can continue the rest of the function as detailed in Frank's answer. Even a non-developer can help filter spam right from the Wordpress dashboard.

Here it is all together:

```
function strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $what) {
        if(($pos = stripos($haystack, $what))!==false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
add_action('gform_pre_submission_1', 'keywords_check');

function keywords_check( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $blacklisted = get_option('blacklist_keys');
    $stop_words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $blacklisted);

    if ( strpos_arr( $value, $stop_words ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Illegal words entered';
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_2_4', 'keywords_check', 10, 4 );
```

If you don't need to test a particular form field like this answer details, I have a solution that will test the WP Comment blacklist against all form fields.

GitHub link below:
https://github.com/adaprile/Gravity-Forms-WP-Comment-Blacklist

I hope this helps someone!